# Show RequestBody metadata dynamically in Swagger Api

Tags: java, rest, post, documentation, swagger-ui

I have an rest api to create an object -- the project is integrated with swagger:

```
@Operation(summary="Create a Team",
        description="May have query params in the future",
        tags = "project", parameters = {

})
@POST
@Path("teams")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public org.project.Team createTeam(Team team) {
}
```

Now, I also have a java object `TeamMetadata` that contains a description for every field in `Team`.
I want to use this `TeamMetadata` in swagger documentation, is that possible?

If not, is this possible in any other technology?

Any help will be appreciated!